# 'find' command alternative for indexing

Tags: matlab, mask

I am using Matlab R2013b. 
In my script I use `find` to get the positions where a boolean mask is 1, and then apply that mask to change values in another vector `vu` For example:

```
bMask = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1];
vIdx = find(bMask==1);
u(vIdx) = 0;
```

Now, Matlab fires a Warning in the editor, claiming that "*To improve performance, use logical indexing instead of* `find`", and suggests the following change:

```
vIdx = bMask == 1;
```

However, this does not get to the same solution that I had with `find`.

So here (is)are my question(s):

- Should I be concerned about this Warning at all (taking into account that `bMask` will probably have dimension >100), or is `find` going to be fine for my purposes?
- If so, what are efficient alternatives to implement this masking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should follow MATLAB's advice. You can use a logical mask like this:

```
u(bMask) = 0;
```

A more robust approach, in case bMask is not a logical mask, is:

```
u(logical(bMask)) = 0;
```

This is faster than using `find`, as MATLAB doesn't have to search through the vector and create an index vector.

A quick performance check:

```
a = rand(100000,1);                 %// Example vector
b = logical(randi(2,100000,1)-1);   %// Logical mask with 1's and 0s

c = a;  %// Backup of a

for ii = 1:1000
    tic; t = toc;   %// Warm up tic/toc function
end

tic
for ii = 1:1000
    a(b) = 0;            %// Perform operation using logical mask
end
t1 = toc

a_temp = a;
a = c;
tic
for ii = 1:1000
    idx = find(b == 1); %// Perform operation using find
    a(idx) = 0;
end
t2 = toc

isequal(a_temp, a)

t1 =
    0.8780  %// Logical mask
t2 =
    1.6748  %// Using find
ans =
     1
```

Comment: I was lacking the `logical` function from your second line! The first line showed the error _Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals_ , and that's what seemed strange

Answer (score 0):

Logical indexing should generally be faster than using find. Where `find` gives you the indices, you can also work with a logical mask. The results should be the same.

```
bMask = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1];
u = rand(size(bMask));
u2 = u;

% find method
vIdx = find(bMask==1);
u(vIdx) = 0;

% logical indexing method
vIdx = bMask == 1
u2(vIdx) = 0;

% check for deviations in result:
all(u==u2) % True
```

Since it returns true, both ways return the same result. Can you provide an example, where the find-solution and the logical-indexing-solution deviate?

Comment: The second method (logical indexing method) needed the `logical` function for me to work, as provided by the other answer. Also, in that case `vIdx` would be the original `bMask`.